# How to I sync Eclipse project with bitbucket?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bitbucket

I am working on a project in Eclipse, and I am trying to push changes to a bitbucket repository.  I have Egit installed, and when I right-click on my project, under the team option, only 'apply patch' appears.  I was hoping for a 'push' or 'pull' and stuff like that.

Does anybody know what I might have overlooked?  There are no other options under the team menu; just 'apply patch'.

Thanks,

Comment: you can see Team---> share project

Comment: No, there are no other options, and now all of the options for importing a Git repository have dissapeared.

Comment: i think buy going to help--> install new software where you can download git..

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but that did not do the trick.